# C# | Entity Framework | An item cannot be removed from a fixed size Array of type

Tags: entity-framework, dbset

In EF, I tried adding a record using syntax:

```
Context.Set<TABLENAME>().Add(TABLEROW)
```

I get this crazy error:
"An item cannot be removed from a fixed size Array of type"

I did a bit of goggling and it suggests I change from DBSet to List from the generated context file of:

```
public partial class GeniusDBContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<TABLENAME> TABLENAMES { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

to

```
public partial class GeniusDBContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual List<TABLENAME> TABLENAMES { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This is ridiculous because if you change the .edmx file, you will lose these changes. Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbSet<>` is correct, there is no need to change it to `List<>`. I think the suggestion found has been be misleading and was not the problem.

To add a new entity, try this:

```
var ctx = new GeniusDBContext();

var entity = new MyEntity();
ctx.MyEntities.Add(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used John's method and it doesn't work on EF6.
So I tricked like this:

```
List<MyEntitie> lstEntity= new List<MyEntitie>();
lstEntity.Add(new MyEntitie
{
    FacID = FacID,
    FoodID = order.FoodID,
    OrderID = IsOrder.ID,
    Quantity = 1,
    ToppingID = -1,
});
db.MyEntities.AddRange(lstEntity);
```

And finally, It working! Hope help everyone